# extracting a 3 digit number always in same position from certain lines in a log file

Tags: powershell

I found powershell script to find each line that includes "sample string" but each line that has the string i want, also has a 3 digit number. I'm only interested in the number and it's always in the same position in the lines I find using the powershell script. So what I really need is a script that finds the lines with "sample string" then extracts char x-y from the string and outputing them to a file would be nice.

```
07.10.2018 20:48:36 Total speed: 599 Sol/s
07.10.2018 20:49:06 Total speed: 601 Sol/s
07.10.2018 20:49:36 Total speed: 600 Sol/s
```

I get the above output with the current script. I'd like to only get the number

using the following code:

```
$InStuff = gc -path Z:\logfile.log | select-object -Last 5
-split [environment]::NewLine

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff) {
    $IS_Item.Split(' ')[-2]

    $Null = $IS_Item -match 'speed: (?<Speed>\d+) Sol'
    $Matches.Speed
    ''
}
```

and im getting following results:

```
54C
598

Sol/s
598

598
598

[A:124,
598

[A:97,
598
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, so we can help you. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A good start is cat the file with the substring modifier. `(get-content file.txt).substring(34,3)` be mindful that get-content can use a lot of RAM on large files so a foreach loop can help. But is more time consuming

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A bunch of people here love answering question related to [tag:powershell], but none of us are mind-readers - you'll have to show us the code that you're having trouble with, otherwise we're going to have a hard time helping you out

Comment: sorry for not being more detailed. im not versed in powershell, before today i never used any scripting in it. right now im using the following: select-string -path Z:\thisfile.log -pattern "Total speed" | select-object -Last 240

Answer (score 1):

this shows two ways to get the "Total speed" number from the sample strings. without your code, you will need to figure out who to make it work in your setup. [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
07.10.2018 20:48:36 Total speed: 599 Sol/s
07.10.2018 20:49:06 Total speed: 601 Sol/s
07.10.2018 20:49:36 Total speed: 600 Sol/s
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    # split on the space, then take the 2nd from the end
    $IS_Item.Split(' ')[-2]

    # capture the numbers after "speed: " and before " Sol"
    #    store them in a named group = "Speed"
    #    get the group from the $Matches automatic variable
    $Null = $IS_Item -match 'speed: (?<Speed>\d+) Sol'
    $Matches.Speed
    ''
    }
```

both of theme give the `599, 601, 600` numbers your samples contain.

hope that helps,
lee

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Lee_Dailey for the script. I edited it a little bit and I'm getting exactly the output I was looking for:

```
$InStuff = sls -path Z:\logfile.log -pattern "Total speed" | select-object -Last 5

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff) {
    $Null = $IS_Item -match 'speed: (?<Speed>\d+) Sol'
    $Matches.Speed
}
```